# A source for $01$-polytopes

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, lattice-polytopes

Can you recommend any books or survey articles on $01$-polytopes, thats is, polytopes with vertices in $\{0,1\}^n$?

I am less interested in random $01$-polytopes, but more in the combinatorial structure of these, which polytopes can be realized as $01$-polytopes, their symmetries, their combinatorial types, interesting families of examples one should know, ...

There seems to be a flood of articles out there, but I am not aware of any book to start reading about a general theory. I suspect that sources on *lattice polytopes* might work as well, but the questions one might ask for this more general class are often different. But maybe some book/article on these contains a section devoted to $01$-polytopes.

Answer (score 3):

There's Ziegler's 1999 [Lectures on 0/1-Polytopes](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9909177), a 45 page survey on the arXiv.  It is also the lead chapter in [*Polytopes - Combinatorics and Computation*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-8438-9), Birkhäuser, 2000.